# different Content-Types in the end point response

Tags: rest, tomcat, wso2-esb

I have a rest API with the Content-Type = application/json, provided by a tomcat server. 
This means that all the responses are supposed to be in the json format.

The rest API is called by the WSO2 ESB to pass some data.

in case that the application providing the rest API is down (but the tomcat server is still up), the tomcat server replays with the http code=404 with the  Content-Type=text/html (sending the HTML page "The requested resource is not available.") what results into the ESB error "Error while building message" exception and ESB crashes and losses the message.

Can you please suggest how to handle such a scenario? I'd need to receive the msg and react on this event. Is there perhaps a way how to dynamically switch content-types?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this with your own modification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="fault_filter_based_http_status_code" trace="disable">
  <filter regex="401" source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')">
    <then>
      <makefault version="soap11">
        <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:Server"/>
        <reason value="Unauthorized to access the resource"/>
        <role/>
      </makefault>
      <send/>
    </then>
    <else/>
  </filter>
  <filter regex="500" source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')">
    <then>
      <makefault version="soap11">
        <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:Server"/>
        <reason value="Internal Server Error Occurred"/>
        <role/>
      </makefault>
      <send/>
    </then>
    <else/>
  </filter>
</sequence>
```

Take a look: http://harshcreationz.blogspot.com/2016/02/common-and-error-handling-sequences.html

Comment: hi Jorge, thank you, I already tried something similar, but the problem is that  the message built fails with the response, thereby there is not http code available yet. What is also strange is that even the FAULT sequence is not entered

Comment: can you share the server response?